# Layout of query result in html

Tags: php, html, css, indexing, undefined

I am trying to arrange profile information on the page in a certain way but I cannot figure out how to use HTML/CSs to position the result from my query where I want it.

HTML:

```
<div id="divFirstnameHeading">
    <h3>New Firstname: </h3>
</div>
<div id="divFirstnameInput">
    <input type="text" id="txtEditFirstname" size="32">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#divFirstnameHeading{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 550px;
}

#divFirstnameInput{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 800px;
}
```

PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($profile)){
        // show the users first name
        echo "<h3 id='oldFirstnameHeading'>First Name: </h3>" . $row["<h3 id='oldFirstname'>'Firstname'</h3>"];
```

Error:

Notice: Undefined index:
'Firstname'

---

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: "Undefined index" has nothing to do with layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error

```
$row["<h3 id='oldFirstname'>'Firstname'</h3>"]
```

Your array should be something like `firstname` so try something like

```
echo "<h3 id='oldFirstnameHeading'>First Name: </h3><h3 id='oldFirstname'>" . $row['Firstname'] . "</h3>";
```

If you post the query itself I can give you a more specific answer